# vim does not execute autocommands on startup, but .vimrc is read

Tags: unix, shell, vim

To save time when creating new scripts I have added the following alias to my .cshrc file:

```
alias skript 'touch \!^; chmod +x \!^; vim \!^'
```

This will create the file I gave as an argument to `skript`, make this file executable, and then open the file in vim.

All this works well, apart from one thing: the `autocmd` lines in my .vimrc file are not executed, even though the settings specified in .vimrc are all in place. If I start vim directly, i.e. not using above alias, everythings works as expected.

In case this is relevant, the `autocmd` lines produce a default header for files with a certain extension, a process during which a template text file has to be read.

In case any of you could help me with getting the header to be produced in files created using my `skript` alias that would be great!

Thanks a lot for your time.

**EDIT**

Here are the `autocmd` lines from my .vimrc file:

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.pl so /home/my_home/Templates/perl_template.txt
autocmd bufnewfile *.pl exe "1," . 10 . "g/creation date:.*/s//creation date: " .strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
autocmd Bufwritepre,filewritepre *.pl execute "normal ma"
autocmd Bufwritepre,filewritepre *.pl exe "1," . 10 . "g/last modified:.*/s/last modified:.*/last modified: " .strftime("%c")
autocmd bufwritepost,filewritepost *.pl execute "normal `a"
```

Comment: +1 just to move your reputation off "666".

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your .vimrc?

Comment: What do you mean saying "start vim directly"? Running 'vim new_script.pl' or 'touch new_script.pl; chmod +x new_script.pl; vim new_script.pl'?  BufNewFile in the autocommand means file that doesn't exists.

Comment: @cutalion Ok, you have spotted the problem, and this nicely illustrates that it's not a good idea to just copy-and-paste something without really understanding what it's doing (as I did with those autocmd lines when I found them on some website). What I meant by 'start vim directly' was 'vim new_script.pl'. If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it (and if you happen to have an idea of how I can use some time saver and still get my header printed, that would be even better ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to close that question, I'll move my comment into the answer :)

BufNewFile in the autocommand means file that doesn't exists. So, it won't run if you create a file before with 'touch' command.

I'd suggest to take a look at [tskeleton_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tskeleton_vim) or [snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim). 
I'm using snipmate with [these snippets](https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets). It has a pretty simple syntax, and there is no problem to add any snippet you may need.

Anyway, you can leave it as is, just run vim directly, without alias, "vim test.pl" and add that autocommand to .vimrc

```
autocmd bufwritepost *.pl silent! !chmod +x %
```